# I have a DOM script on NodeJS. It works on local, but it seems like won't open the browser on a VPS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, server, vps

I'm trying to run a script that opens a browser and execute DOM scripts in it. It works fine on local, but it seems like it won't open the browser on the VPS server.

When I try to open a browser in the server, it gives me this error:

```
# google-chrome --no-sandbox
[0420/120315.054012:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0420/120315.054164:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
Trace/breakpoint trap
root@20230221fRa:~# [0420/120315.079917:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(355)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

Open a browser in the VPS server successfully